# Is this a good way to create a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quiz

I'm building a simple quiz app and wanted to make it more scalable by putting my code into an object. The parameters list looks a bit messy to me. Is this a normal way to use an object or is there a better way?

Thanks

```
// above here I have a JSON object with questions:
var quiz = new question($('#quiz-container'), $('.alert'), 0, [], questions[0].level[0]);

// for debugging
console.log(quiz);

function question(quizContainer, alert, questionCounter, selection, level) {
    this.quizContainer = quizContainer;
    this.alert = alert;
    this.questionCounter = questionCounter;
    this.selection = selection;
    this.level = level;

    function createQuestion(index) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: I see issues with the current code. For instance, I think `createQuestion`should be the single point to create an object (and should not be possible to call `new Question()`). The number of arguments passed to the constructor can be reduced too (`#quiz-container` is a global unique object, probably `.alert` is unique too), other default values such as 0 or [] can be set inside the constructor (no need to pass them as arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the createQuestion function you could simply do the following

```
this.createQuestion = function(index){ 
    // your code
};
```

You can create public and private variables in a object. The easiest example I can give for this is using the following code.

```
function someObject(publicInput, privateInput) {

    this.public = publicInput;

    var private = privateInput;

    this.getPrivate = function(){
        return private;
    }
}

var newObject = new someObject(true, false);

console.log(newObject.public); // returns true
console.log(newObject.private); // returns undefined
console.log(newObject.getPrivate()); // returns false
```

As you can see the private variable can only be accessed from inside the object, which is why I've added a getPrivate() function to return this variable.